# programmicaly switch electric power

Tags: switches, pc

I am an experienced programmer (mostly C#), I also know how to get along with physical electrical circuits, but do not know anything about how to start the simple task of connecting a switch (12v or 220v, my choose) to a computer and controlling it through the code. It's just about switching on\off the light, so it's hard for me to believe I have to have very smart cards.

I know, this question is a duplicate of... but no! There is no place that explains in simple steps are required, only vague indications of electrical components.. I need something like: a. Materials required, b. technical steps (what to compose why)

Comment: There are plenty of places which host walk-thoughs for various computer-controlled appliances (starting with the guy who redirected STDERR to his printer and attached the power cord to the printing head so that his printer would pull the plug in case of errors). This site isn't just hosting any because it's not the kind of format we want here.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious solution would be an off-the-shelf USB relay board.  Lots of people sell them.  Using a relay provides isolation between the computer and the thing being switched.

Comment: thank! I see many types and prices in the market. Can I be sure I can run them in any programming language? actualy I expect to c#.

Comment: @lomed Either look for a USB device that enumerates as a virtual COM port and use the usual .net means for accessing it and use the manual that comes with it, or else buy one that includes a driver and a .net interface for you-- documented well, I hope.

Comment: Forget USB. For a fixed installation go WiFi. I think this Internet thing is going to be big! Look for WiFi switched socket (or "plug") or WiFi relay controller.

Comment: @Transistor, such https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESP8266?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that since software is your forte that you purchase ready-made devices. This saves you a load of work with live equipment and associated risks. Otherwise you have to purchase modules, power supplies, solid-state relays and try to wire them up and mount them safely and securely.

[image]

*Figure 1. Devices such as the Belkin WoMo may suit.*

I haven't used the Belkin equipment and don't know if it is suitable for your application.

The [Openhab](http://openhab.org) project might be of interest. They have a Linux based system that will run on a Raspberry Pi with drivers / protocols to talk to just about everything.